# Why using Image.save() (from Pillow in Python) with variables is not working?

Tags: python

On a Python course, I have to write a script to  transform a bunch of images (with wrong format(.tiff) and size) to '.jpeg' and save them with the same name to another folder!

The problem is it won't save it to the directory I want (even on  the same directory) using the path + file variable + the image format. I used the os.path.join() method too but it did not work either. I managed to do it a few times but not in the directory I want. Can you give me some advice? Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import os

files = os.listdir('/home/dani/images')
if not os.path.exists('/home/dani/images/opt/icons'):
    os.makedirs('/home/dani/images/opt/icons')
for file in files[1:]:
    if not os.path.isdir('/home/dani/images/'+ file): 
        im = Image.open('/home/dani/images/'+file)
        im.convert('RGB').rotate(-90).resize((128,\
    128)).save('/home/dani/images/opt/icons/'+file +'.jpeg')
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: python can't load code from image to run it, mouse can't select code on image to copy it - so using image with code is only waste of time.

Comment: first generate filename for new file and next use `print()` to see if you created correct path. Maybe your path is wrong.

Comment: You could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - maybe it never run code which reads image - so it also doesn't run code which saves it. OR maybe it reads wrong folder which doesn't have images.

Comment: I used the print function to see if it reads the image and it does it. The problem is it does not write as it should!

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it? You could use `print()` to check what you get with `'/home/dani/images/opt/icons/'+file +'.jpeg'` - if you have file `image.tiff` then it should create name with double extension `image.tiff.jpeg`. You could check if this path exists. You can also split `convert.rotate.resize.save` in separated lines and check which part doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes saving has problems with permission. Try saving the file in the same folder you have your .py file.
If saving in the same folder works, then the problem is a permission. Try `os.umask()`